# recover (pontrjagin) ring structure from the localization (w.r.t. $\pi_0$)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, localization

Let $R$ be a ring and $S$ a given multiplicative subset of $R$. Suppose we know the multiplication structure of $S$. If we know the ring structure of $R[S^{-1}]$, the localization of $R$ with respect to $S$, could we recover the ring structure of $R$?

In particular, if $X$ is a $H$-space, $R=H_*(X)$, $S=\pi_0(X)$,  and we know the ring structure of $H_*(X)[\pi_0X^{-1}]$, can we obtain the ring structure of $H_*(X)$?

Comment: For any $R$ with $\mathbb{Z}\leq R\leq\mathbb{Q}$ and for $S=\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$, $R[S^{-1}]=\mathbb{Q}$. Maybe you want some extra conditions on $R$ and $S$?

Comment: I want to consider $R$ as the homology Pontrjagin ring of an $H$-space, and $S$ the path-conencted component of the $H$-space contained in $0$-th homology.